# Count of unique nested documents in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, nosql

The problem domain has got kiosks on which many tokens are displayed. A token is issued by only one issuer and it can be present on multiple kiosks. The kiosk logic accepts/refuses users based on what tokens are present on that kiosk.

Our Elastic mapping is this:

```
"mappings": {
  "Kiosk": {
     "dynamic": "strict",
     "properties": {
        "kioskId": {
           "type": "keyword"
        },
        "token": {
           "type": "nested",
           "include_in_parent": true,
           "properties": {
              "tokenId": {
                 "type": "keyword"
              },
              "issuer": {
                 "type": "keyword"
              }
           }
        }
     }
  }
}
```

Here are two typical documents:

```
Kiosk1  
   "kioskId": "123",
   "token": {
      "tokenId": "fp1",
      "issuer": "i1"

Kiosk2    
   "kioskId": "321",
   "token": [
      {
         "tokenId": "fp1",
         "issuer": "i1"
      },
      {
         "tokenId": "fp2",
         "issuer": "i2"
      }
   ]
```

Now, the ask is to find count of all the unique tokens in the system bucketed by issuers. There's been no luck in finding them. We tried this query:

```
POST _search
{
   "aggs": {
      "state": {
         "nested": {
            "path": "token"
         },
         "aggs": {
            "TOKENS_BY_ISSUER": {
               "terms": {
                  "field": "token.issuer"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

This obviously gives this result:

```
"aggregations": {
      "state": {
         "doc_count": 3,
         "TOKENS_BY_ISSUER": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
               {
                  "key": "i1",
                  "doc_count": 2
               },
               {
                  "key": "i2",
                  "doc_count": 1
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   }
```

Is there a way to know that there are only two tokens in the system each issued by i1 and i2? Something like this...

```
"buckets": [
            {
               "key": "i1",
               "doc_count": 1
            },
            {
               "key": "i2",
               "doc_count": 1
            }
         ]
```

If not, where has mapping gone wrong? I feel it's not an unusual mapping though. Do note that I have truncated the mapping posted here for brevity, we have further nested levels under tokens. Those additional nested levels carry fields which are specific to a token and its parent kiosk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your query to match something like this

```
    {
   "query": {
      "match_all": {}
   },
   "aggs":{
      "state": {
         "nested": {
            "path": "token"
         },
         "aggs": {
            "TOKENS_BY_ISSUER": {
               "terms": {
                  "field": "token.issuer"
               },
               "aggs":{
                   "distinct_tokens":{
                       "cardinality":{"field":"token.tokenId"}
                   }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Note:

1. The cardinality aggregation in elasticsearch has an error rate associated with it as it uses the HyperLogLog approximation technique to calculate unique field values in a bucket.Hence error rate for the same would increase as the number of tokens in your system increases.
2. While indexing the kiosk1 document the token should be a vector/array so as to make sure you are not doing anything wrong while indexing.

In order to increase the accuracy of the cardinality aggregation try with increasing the precision_threshold controller in the POST query. This one comes at a cost of more memory utilisation.

Checkout link for further details
[Elasticsearch Cardinality Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/cardinality.html)

Would rather recommend designing this based on the requirement and only if you are ready to accept the error percentages when under scale.

Comment: Thanks. This helped but as you pointed out that it's approximate which is not usable for our scenario where we need exact result.

Comment: Its accurate and also super fast in many use cases. 
But would not recomment when unique token.tokenId in your system crosses a few 100K.